# How can a method receive string as input and give int as output

Tags: java, string, methods

I am doing a task in Java which asks me to write a method that receives a string of ints like 1,1,3,4,4 and returns one of those numbers which is unique

```
public class test {

    public static int main(String s, int r) {
        String[] studentsarray = s.split(",");
        int[] intArray = new int[studentsarray.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < studentsarray.length; i++) {
            String numberAsString = studentsarray[i];
            intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(numberAsString);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < intArray.length; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < intArray.length; k++) {
                if (intArray[k] == intArray[j]) {
                    int result = 0;
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my program. I am not sure how to pass a string to the method. Should I write the string in the brackets after the method's name together with the return type ? Currently this is not working, I don't know why

Comment: did you read (and understand) the compilers error message?

Comment: Also your class has no *valid* main method, one that the JVM will start the program from.

Answer (score 1):

Your main allways get a String array ... so write another method or use the first parameter (args[0]) as your input.

```
public int getUniqueInt(String ints){
     String[] strIntsArr = ints.split(',');
     int[] intArr = new int[strIntsArr.length];

     for(int i = 0; i<intArr.length; i++){
         intArr[i] = Integer.getInteger(strIntsArr[i]);
     }

     //now you have all ints in the intArr and only have to get the unique one
}
```

**EDIT:**

- a main method in java is allways void (has no return)
- a main method in java allways awaits a String[] as params
- a main method in java ist allways static and public

For more information, have a look at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/#MAIN).

Your main should be something like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String yourintString = "1,2,3,4,5";
    //or if you want it as paramter (commandline)
    String yourintString = args[0];

    System.out.println("Unique int: "+ getUniqueInt(yourintString));
}
```

Comment: When I try to combine those 2 methods in one program I can't get it to work. When I return the int from the method I get `yourintString can not be resolved to a variable` thats in the System.out,println line of the program

Comment: check the spelling, i have had a typo in my sample. if you can´t find the mistake, please post the code in your main